# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when using ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use a route to pass parameters via the url using **ui.router** however i'm stuck at the first hurdle as i can't seem to get the ui-router to register so i get the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I've included my ui.router js file in a config file that looks something like this:
`'./build/lib/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'`

I then include **ui.router** in my module:

```
topic.Module = angular.module('topic', ['ui.router']);
```

and try to create a sample state like so:

```
topic.Module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Is there anything obvious that i'm doing or not doing that would result in this not working or getting the above error? I've cut the contents of the state down completely to confirm nothing else was causing the error.

I've tried including `'ui-router'` instead of `'ui.router'` i've included in the main app module also with the same results.

Comment: it should be ui.router not ui-router when injecting the service. Check for spelling these service names are case sensitive. In my case I have put $StateProvider instead of $stateProvider.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone coming across this, it seems `$urlRouterProvider` is required as well as `$stateProvider`.

So include `$urlRouterProvider` and add the following to set a default route:
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`

so the above example would look like this:

```
topic.Module.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: $urlRouteProvider is not a must to injected when configuring. But it is a good parties to have a default route for the routing.